# Получить дату из базы sql в php?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть база данных MySQL, есть поле date формата timestamp.
Выглядит дата в формате "2014-06-03 15:45:48".

Как сделать так что бы дата вывелась например в таком формате

3 июня 2014 г. или 03.06.2014 ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://www.shulga.in.ua/blog/use_of_mysql_date_format.html)

> Пример:
>
> `SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(date_registration,'%d.%m.%Y') as date_reg FROM users`
>
> даты будут в следующем формате: `04.09.2007`  и будут находиться в поле `date_reg`, не `date_registration` (в возвращаемом массиве будет новое поле `date_reg`)